# Display content on single product page in Woocommerce based on category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm sooooo close - but I can't get this last little bit.

I am adding the authors name to books we have for sale in woo. The style needs to be different from the book title so I'm using a custom meta field to put it under the title and style it the way I want. I have everything working and where I want it, now I just need for it only show on a particular category instead of on all products.

There seems to me to be two ways to do this. 
1 - Only display it for products in a particular category 
2 - Only display it if there is content.

I'm currently trying to only display if it's a particular category, but while writing this, its seems a more elegant solution to only display if content exists.

Here's what I have

```
function cn_add_add_subhead_to_title() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

 if ( is_product() && has_term( 'books-media', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    ?>
    <div class="cn-subhead">
      by <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ); ?>  
    </div>
    <?php

 } 

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cn_add_add_subhead_to_title', 6 );
```

This doesn't display anywhere, but when I take out the if statement it shows on all products.

Any idea where I went awry?

Comment: Have you added `cn_add_add_subhead_to_title()` to an action hook via `add_action()`? Or are you calling it directly from a template?

Comment: Its added to a hook - ' add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cn_add_add_subhead_to_title', 6 );'

Comment: Are you sure that `books-media` is the slug of your category? Are you sure that `_text_field` is the name of your custom meta? Are you sure you saved it correctly? Otherwise, the code is correct and once modified for my own product category and meta field, displays "By X" just below the title.

Comment: Hi Helga - I know I'm pulling from the correct slug because the content shows just fine until I add the if statement.  I double checked the category slug and that's correct as well. I turned off the login for now if you want to have a look at the dev site. Only one book has the author added at the moment and I have disabled the if statement for now. [link](http://ecbiz147.inmotionhosting.com/~comple73/product/the-weather-wizards-5-year-weather-diary-robert-alden-rubin-editor/)

Comment: Is that book in the `books-media` category specifically? Or is it a sub-category? It looks like `books-media-weather`. I've proposed an alternative below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer in context Helga - this snippet will add a custom meta field to the woocommerce product editing dashboard, save the content and display it under the product title on the single product view.

```
/* add product subhead custom field to woocommerce product dashboard  */

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

 global $woocommerce, $post;

echo '<div class="options_group">';

woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
array( 
    'id'          => '_text_field', 
    'label'       => __( 'MY-LABEL', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => 'Author',
    'desc_tip'    => 'true',
    'description' => __( 'This text will show below the product title.', 'woocommerce' ) 
)
);

echo '</div>';

}

/* Save woo custom field */
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

$woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

}

/* add author below title on single product */

function cn_add_subhead_to_title() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
    if( $meta != '' ) {
    ?>
    <div class="cn-subhead">
      by <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ); ?>  
    </div>
    <?php

 }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cn_add_subhead_to_title', 6 );
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply test for the presence of the meta? If you don't save the meta in the other categories it will never display:

```
function cn_add_add_subhead_to_title() {

  global $post;

 if ( $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ) ) {
    ?>
    <div class="cn-subhead">
      <?php printf( __( 'by %s', 'textdomain' ), $meta ); ?>  
    </div>
    <?php

 } 

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cn_add_add_subhead_to_title', 6 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Helga - Thanks for your interest and help. I had a little time so I decided to try the other route of only displaying the meta if there was content instead of based on category. This may be a more flexible solution anyway, leaving the field open to any sort of subhead they want instead of limiting it only to Authors.

This the code that worked:

```
/* add author below title on single product */

function cn_add_add_subhead_to_title() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
    if( $meta != '' ) {
    ?>
    <div class="cn-subhead">
      by <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ); ?>  
    </div>
    <?php

 }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cn_add_add_subhead_to_title', 6 );
```

Comment: Helga, I see you keep a blog of code snippets. Here's the whole shooting match I used to add a custom meta field under General in the product dashboard, save it, and display it under the product title on the single product page.